# Can anybody tell me that why factorial of 0! is 1. can you proof it in deatil?

Tags: real-numbers, factorial

In many places, I have read that $0!$ is $1$ but as I know that factorial is multiple of the number and all the number before it up to $1$. But according to it $0!$ should be $0\times0$ that is $0$ then why it is $1$ . Please explain in detail.

Comment: You can't prove a definition. You can justify why you are adopting it.

Comment: $n!$ is the product of the integers $k$ such that $1\le k\le n$. I don't see why the product of the integers $k$ such that $1\le k\le 0$ should be $0\times 0$.

Comment: By the previous comment, $0!$ is the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

Comment: for n > 1, $n! = (n-1)!$, so by convention 0! is considerd to be 1. And there are i suppose others justifications for exmple because it is usufull  for writting some formula implying factorial

Comment: If we would include $0$ as well, EVERY factorial would be $0$. So , of course , $0$ is omitted. And then there are no positive integers upto $0$ and the empty product is , per definition , $1$ , hence $0!=1$ is justified.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} = n.$$  Set $n=1$ and solve for the denominator.

Comment: Ummm.... why the downvote?  Especially because I was first... and my solution used later by emacs... (which has no downvote).

Comment: I upvoted it because there's nothing wrong with it. I have no idea why it got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a recursive definition of integer factorial as

$$n!=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } n=1\\
n\cdot(n-1)!,& \text{ if } n>1\\
\end{cases}\tag 1$$

so that $1!=1$, $2!=2$, $3!=6$ etc.

Now you can use the defintion in "reverse":

$$(n-1)! = \frac{n!}n\tag 2$$

Which yields $$0!=(1-1)!= \frac{1!}1 = 1\tag 3$$

However, you cannot go any further, because for $(-1)!$ yuo would divide by $0$ in $(2)$.  This reflects the fact that the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) has a pole at $0$. Remember that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.

As an aside, $(3)$ means that we could have defined factorial starting at $n=0$ like

$$n!=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } n=0\\
n\cdot(n-1)!,& \text{ if } n>0\\
\end{cases}\tag 4$$

which yields the exact same values like $(1)$ plus one backstep.

Answer (score 0):

There's no proof for why $0! = 1$ because that's a definition, but we can at least explain why we've adopted it. Here are some reasons why.

(1) - There is exactly one permutation of zero objects: with nothing to permute, the only "rearrangement" is to do nothing.

(2) - In calculus, this definition matches the gamma function ${\displaystyle 0!=\Gamma (0+1)=1}$, and the gamma function must have this value to be continuous.

(3) - In calculus, this definition is convenient for power series representations like $e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

(4) - If $n = 0$, then the definition of $n!$ as a product of nonnegative integers involves the product of no nonnegative integers at all. In fact, the empty product, which is a product of no factors, is equal to the multiplicative identity.